# HTML: Navigate to a different url using button

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a link or a button so that users can navigate to different urls (needs to be generated in a js function based on values selected in multiple dropdown)

I tried with a button but it doesn't navigate to the link, and with  not able to change values of href it adds to previous values.

Can you please help

Comment: Perhaps you should show what you have tried

Comment: Any example what you have tried?

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function link(url){
    window.location.assign(url);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="link('http://www.stackoverflow.com/')">Go to Stack Overflow without using an &lt;a&gt;!</button>
```

Comment: It is still navigating to file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/www.cnn.com instead of www.cnn.com  I used var1= "www.cnn.com"; 
 
     window.location.assign(var1);

Comment: Worked... my mistake was that for URL i was not using http://

Comment: You're welcome. Took me ages to find that code when I first went looking. Funny how the most important and powerful commands are always the hardest to learn about. Just in case you need it, `location.reload()` reloads the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
https://jsfiddle.net/ykc8mLwj/

```
  $(function() {
        $("#id-of-your-select").on("change", function() {
            $("#id-of-your-link").attr("href", $(this).val());
        });
    }
```

Comment: and why? jQuery is cool :)

Comment: show your full code of this and i will show you that works :)

Comment: Found the issue :) works now. I am new to Jquery so did a rookie mistake :)  Thank you so much